# How do you get the aurelia-api plugin from Spoonx to work with the current webpack config that does not use coreBundles.aurelia

Tags: webpack, aurelia

System

Windows 10,
Webpack 4.1.1,
aurelia-bootstrapper 2.3.1,
aurelia-api 3.2.1

Below are the installation instructions for the aurelia-api plugin.  Website for [aurelia-api](https://aurelia-api.spoonx.org/)

**Webpack install**

Run npm i aurelia-api --save from your project root.
Add 'aurelia-api' in the coreBundles.aurelia section of your webpack.config.js

The problem is that the current version of the webpack config for aurelia no longer uses coreBundles.aurelia.

Where in my webpack.config.js do I reference the aurelia-api plugin?

In the browser(electron) debug console I am receiving error:

Error: Unable to find module with ID: aurelia-api.

Thanks.

More info:

In my main.js I have the plugin declared as so.

```
import { PLATFORM } from "aurelia-pal";

 .plugin(PLATFORM.moduleName('aurelia-api', config => {
    config.registerEndpoint('auth',dfconfig.loginurl() );
    config.registerEndpoint('api',apiconfig.baseurl(),{headers: {"X-DreamFactory-API-Key": apiconfig.APP_API_KEY, "X-DreamFactory-Application-Name": apiconfig.APP_NAME}});
  }))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having some issues with registering endpoints, but I think importing the library in your main.js should do the trick for you:

```
import { PLATFORM } from "aurelia-pal";
import 'aurelia-api';
```